# AWS S3 Upload Integrity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using S3 to backup large files that are critical to my business. Can I be confident that once uploaded, these files are verified for integrity and are intact?

There is a lot of documentation around scalability and availability but I couldn't find any information talking about integrity and/or checksums.

Comment: Check `Content-MD5` header here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

Answer (score 3):

When uploading to S3, there's an optional request header (which in my opinion should *not* be optional, but I digress), `Content-MD5`.  If you set this value to the base64 encoding of the MD5 hash of the request body, S3 will outright reject your upload in the event of a mismatch, thus preventing the upload of corrupt data.

The `ETag` header will be set to the hex-encoded MD5 hash of the object, for single part uploads (with an exception for some types of server-side encryption).

For multipart uploads, the `Content-MD5` header is set to the same value, but for each part.

When S3 combines the parts of a multipart upload into the final object, the `ETag` header is set to the hex-encoded MD5 hash of the concatenated binary-encoded (raw bytes) MD5 hashes of each part, plus `-` plus the number of parts.

When you ask S3 to do that final step of combining the parts of a multipart upload, you have to give it back the ETags it gave you during the uploads of the original parts, which is supposed to assure that what S3 is combining is what you think it is combining.  Unfortunately, there's an API request you can make to ask S3 about the parts you've uploaded, and some lazy developers will just ask S3 for this list and then send it right back, which the documentarion warns against, but hey, it "seems to work," right?

Multipart uploads are required for objects over 5GB and optional for uploads over 5MB.

Correctly used, these features provide assurance of intact uploads.

If you are using Signature Version 4, which also optional in older regions, there is an additional integrity mechanism, and this one isn't optional (if you're actually using V4): uploads must have a request header `x-amz-content-sha256`, set to the hex-encoded SHA-256 hash of the payload, and the request will be denied if there's a mismatch here, too.

**My take: Since some of these features are optional, you can't trust that any tools are doing this right unless you audit their code.**

I don't trust anybody with my data, so for my own purposes, I wrote my own utility, internally called "pedantic uploader," which uses no SDK and speaks directly to the REST API. It calculates the sha256 of the file and adds it as `x-amz-meta-...` metadata so it can be fetched with the object for comparison.  When I upload compressed files (gzip/bzip2/xz) I store the sha of both compressed and uncompressed in the metadata, and I store the compressed and uncompressed size in octets in the metadata as well.

Note that `Content-MD5` and `x-amz-content-sha256` are *request* headers.  They are not returned with downloads. If you want to save this information in the object metadata, as I described here.

Within EC2, you can easily download an object without actually saving it to disk, just to verify its integrity.  If the EC2 instance is in the same region as the bucket, you won't be billed for data transfer if you use an instance with a public IPv4 or IPv6 address, a NAT instance, an S3 VPC endpoint, or through an IPv6 egress gateway.   (You'll be billed for NAT Gateway data throughput if you access S3 over IPv4 through a NAT Gateway).  Obviously there are ways to automate this, but manually, if you select the object in the console, choose Download, right-click and copy the resulting URL, then do this:

```
$ curl -v '<url from console>' | md5sum # or sha256sum etc.
```

Just wrap the URL from the console in single `'` quotes since it will be pre-signed and will include `&` in the query string, which you don't want the shell to interpret.

Comment: I've been using the browser to upload files. Looks like the cli does perform a checksum (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-faq.html). Does anyone know if the browser performs a checksum too?

Comment: SInce this post, it seems this has become an embedded feature of S3 CLI upload. I'm not entirely sure tho...
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-faq.html

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an MD5 checksum locally, and then verify that against the MD5 checksum of the object on S3 to ensure data integrity. [Here is a guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/)